# How to select the last cell in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, date, range, formula

I've got a spreadsheet that updates throughout the day with data, I need to be able to grab the last cell in a column but for certain date ranges, not just the last cell in the column.

Column C contains the data I need, column A and B update with the date and time, (some cells in column A could be blank too). Column D I can change to make column E display the latest data for the selected date.

Here's what I've got so far to put in column E:

```
VLOOKUP(D1, $A:$C,3,FALSE)
```

I've managed to get data from my formula but only the first entry. For example if I enter the date 17/05/2016 it will return '5'. Whereas I need the more recent data '28'.

Example sheet:

[image: Example sheet]

```
     A     |    B     |    C   |    D    |    E
16/05/2016 | 08:00:00 | 3      | date    | data
16/05/2016 | 12:00:00 | 7       
16/05/2016 | 18:00:00 | 15      
16/05/2016 | 22:00:00 | 27      
17/05/2016 | 08:00:00 | 5       
17/05/2016 | 12:00:00 | 11      
17/05/2016 | 18:00:00 | 21      
17/05/2016 | 22:00:00 | 28      
18/05/2016 | 08:00:00 | 4       
18/05/2016 | 12:00:00 | 13      
18/05/2016 | 18:00:00 | 19      
18/05/2016 | 22:00:00 | 30
```

I've only just started getting my head around excel formulas so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ALWAYS better to post text sample data than a screen shot.  That is why I rolled back your edit on you.  If you want to keep using vlookup, you can change false to TRUE.  but column A needs to be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @ForwardEd- To use vlookup with TRUE it would be necessary to create a column with `=A2+B2` and sort that column in ascending order.

Comment: @user704808 no he does not, as he is not searching with time currently.  column B does not get used since the question asked specifically for the last cell in a date range.  Now if the quest was for the latest times within a date range that would the scenario you are presenting,  Though a sort ascending on column A and then on column B as a secondary would produce the same results.

Comment: @ForwardEd- Good points. He could indeed sort on A then on B rather than sort on a new, combined column. But he must do one or the other (and indeed already has based on the sample data) if I understand correctly his goal "to make column E display the latest data for the selected date".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=INDEX(C2:C13,MATCH(D3,A2:A13,1))
```

INDEX/MATCH is a very powerful combination.  It can perform the same job as VLOOKUP and then a bit more.  VLOOKUP is restricted to searching the first column and returning information to the right.  With MATCH you can search any column, and you can return information from any column (even to the left which vlookup cant do)

If you start reading with the MATCH function, it searches for the value in D3 within the range A2:A13 and return an integer representing the row the value of D3 was found it.  The 1 at the end of match tell match to look for that last entry that D3 exceeded.  This means that column A needs to be sorted in ASCENDING order

INDEX uses the integer from MATCH and goes down that many rows in in specified range.  so if match returned 1, then it would read C2.

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: This is great thank you! My actual spreadsheet is across multiple workbooks so I just edited the locations a little and it worked brilliantly! Super fast response too so extra thanks!